# VBA Textbox name length: "not a legal object"

Tags: vba, textbox

When I'm trying to change textbox default name to "Energia_elektryczna_czynna" (26 characters in total) I get an error: "Not a legal object name".

When I googled I found out that:

> Form and control names must start with a letter and can be a maximum of 40 characters — including letters, numbers, and underscores (_).

Why can't I make the change then ?

Comment: Are you using special characters in the name? Sometimes this kind of thing is caused by encoding problems.

Comment: No, I only use latin alphabet even though my native language is Polish.

Comment: It works just find for me, can we see your code?

Comment: Ok, I think it's because I used copy-paste but how this affects the name ? I've copied the label caption. I have no idea. It works when I enter the name manually.

Comment: Perhaps you also accidentally copied lead/trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy/paste, especially from Excel, there are often whitespace symbols left that are not visible in the `TexBox`-like controls. Another copy/paste problematic app is Lync for me, where I always grab more than I want.

I suggest checking such copied texts *by pasting into Notepad++ with **Show Whitespace** option ON*. That way, you will ensure there is no whitespace in unexpected parts of your strings.

I copied the name of the text box from your question, and pasted into the Properties field, and it worked OK:

[image]

Miłej pracy życzę!

Comment: Yes, it seems so. By the way, how come I can use over 40 characters in the textbox name when the information I quoted in the question says 40 is maximum ? I 've just checked and it worked. Even when I used over 40 special characters (Polish letters). Both entered manually and copied from Word.

Comment: The length of the control name is up to 128 characters. And you can insert any special characters since VBA is Unicode unaware. Since you have Polish set as your default language for non-Unicode apps, you can work with Polish extended characters in VBA with no issues. Try with Russian: `Вася_Пупкин`. Excel will try to normalize, I guess to question marks.